# Cocoa - screen capture and draw (retina)

Tags: objective-c, image, cocoa, screen-capture, retina

I`m try get screen capture from retina display, and draw this image on window.

I can get capture

```
CGDirectDisplayID displayId = CGMainDisplayID()
CGImage imageRef = CGDisplayCreateImage(displayId)
```

image have a size 2560x1600

Now, i need draw this image on window. But if, i resize window to full screen, window return size 1280x800. If i wont draw image on window, i need scale image to 1280x800. Image lost quality, this is not good.

Please help me, how i can get screen capture from retina display and draw his on window, without lost quality ?

Comment: NSImage can have multiple representation . You can keep both resolution in the image as representation . Please refer this link for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681902/issues-with-nsimage-add-representation-in-retina-display

Comment: for  example

    CGDirectDisplayID displayID = CGMainDisplayID();
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGDisplayCreateImage(displayID); 

    NSSize sizeRef;
    sizeRef.width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    sizeRef.height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    NSImage *imageCG = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef size:sizeRef];

    NSBitmapImageRep *imgRep = [[imageCG representations] objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSData *data = [imgRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType
            properties: nil];
    [data writeToFile: @"~/Desktop/file.png" atomically: NO];

I right understand you ?

Comment: i check image, his have one representation.

Comment: You can keep 1x,2x resolution as represetation in your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out actual window size in pixels by passing its frame to this method:

`-[NSWindow convertRectToBacking:]`

Answer (score 0):

Just draw the image to the view's bounds. In theory this is a scaling operation, but in reality it's not because the view's bounds are in points, not pixels. The backing buffer for the view is at the same DPI as the original screen capture, so it will be a straight blit. No detail will be lost.